# Using High Level Shader Language for computational algorithms

Tags: cuda, gpu, hlsl

So, I heard that some people have figured out ways to run programs on the GPU using High Level Shader Language and I would like to start writing my own programs that run on the GPU rather than my CPU, but I have been unable to find anything on the subject.

Does anyone have any experience with writing programs for the GPU or know of any documentation on the subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For computation, **CUDA** and **OpenCL** are more suitable than shader languages. For CUDA, I highly recommend the book **[CUDA by Example](http://fishmoth.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/cuda-by-example/)**. The book is aimed at absolute beginners to this area of programming.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I think to start is to

1. Have a CUDA Card from Nvidia
2. Download Driver + Toolkit + SDK
3. Build the examples
4. Read the Cuda Programming Guide
5. Start to recreate the cudaDeviceInfo example
6. Try to allocate memory in the gpu
7. Try to create a little kernel

From there you should be able to gain enough momentum to learn the rest.
Once you learn CUDA then OpenCL and other are a breeze.
I am suggesting CUDA because is the one most widely supported and tested.